# python vector * vector------> matrix

Tags: python, graphics

In the python computer graphics kit, there is a **vec3** type for the representation of three-component vectors, but how can I do the following multiplication:

A three-component vector multiply by its transpose result in a 3*3 matrix, like the following example:

```
a = vec3(1,1,1)
matrix_m = a * a.transpose()
```

Anyone knows such a library that can handle multiplying a matrix of dimension 1*3 by another one of dimension 3*1 and result in a matrix of 3*3.

Sorry, I have to clarify a bit more about this. I am talking about matrix math. 
It is like:

[a0, a1, a2]*[a0, a1, a2]T = [a0*a0, a0*a1, a0*a2; a1*a0, a1*a1, a1*a2;a2*a0, a2*a1, a2*a2]

Maybe I can try write a function myself, it is so straightforward.....

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: `a * a'` Would just be the dot product of `a` by itself. Which would be a scalar value. I don't understand how you expect to get a matrix out of this.

Comment: @JoelCornett Obviously multiplying 3x1 by 1x3 would create a 3x3 matrix. Is that what he wants? The way I understood it, that was the problem, not the desired result...

Comment: @TC1: of course >.<, for some reason I was thinking row vectors.

Comment: @TC1  yes, exactly like what you said. I want to compute the result of multiplication of two matrix, one is 3*1 and the other is 1*3 and result in a 3*3 matrix.  I just cannot find a library that supports arbitrary dimension matrix

Comment: will [numpy.matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) `*` multiplication operator help?

Comment: It might help to know this math jargon: To multiply vec times vec and get a 3x3 matrix is the "outer product".   The dot product, a scalar, is the "inner product"

Comment: @DarenW I think that might just confuse him more, since both inner and outer will be `dot()` in numpy and most lin alg libraries (as opposed to the cross product).

Answer (score 1):

Some vector math software, such as MATLAB, happily keep track of column vectors and row vectors as separate types of things.  Python's Numpy doesn't, but does offer numpy.outer(A,B).  Unfortunately, the Graphics Kit (I assume you refer to http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/) doesn't track rows vs columns, use numpy (which would be huge overkill), or provide a vector x vector --> matrix outer product.   It looks like you'll have to write your own function to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will write one myself.